# In BIND, forward DNS query for specific domain to specific nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, forwarding

Windows Server 2003 has this feature where you can forward queries for domain "example.com" to specific nameserver (not the default DNS server).

How do i set this up in BIND? For example, i want to set up forwarding for local TLD to specific local nameserver.

Bind version 9.6

### Working configuration

As Khaled noted, we can use forwarders statement in zone clause. It worked with the following configuration:

```
zone "local." IN {
   type forward;
   forward only;
   forwarders { 10.10.1.9; };
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html). You can use the `forward` and `forwarders` statements inside your zone block.

```
forward ( only | first )
forwarders { ipv4_addr }
```